# Different WiFi signal strengths on different commands

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, command-line, netsh

I'm connected to a WiFi network AIRWOLF. The two following commands on Windows 7 show different signal strengths. Why?

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid
```

[image: netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid]

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

[image: netsh wlan show interfaces]

The signal strengths don't change over time.

Comment: I'm getting the same value in both cases, so no idea what's up.